# Can't cast qgraphicsitem

Tags: qt, casting, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

OK, i think the error may be obvious but at this time i can't find it.

I have:

```
class GraphViewCustom : public QGraphicsView
{
...
protected:
  void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);
}
```

and similar classes GraphSceneCustom (derived from QGraphicsScene) and GraphPixmapItemCustom (from QGraphicsPixmapItem). In above wheelEvent(), I have a line like this:

```
qgraphicsitem_cast(items().first());
```

I have deleted left side of substitution for readability and less complication. And at this line i get

> no matching function for call to 'qgraphicsitem_cast(QGraphicsItem*&)'

What am I doing wrong? I suppose this mistake is obvious (what are my most common mistake - i rarely make hard ones. But when i do they are really hard).

And yes, I have added the header of QGraphicsItem class.

Comment: Nevermind, it was an obvious mistake. There is no <Class> clause. So with qgraphicsItem_cast<GraphPixmapItemCustom*>(items().first()) it's OK. I still can't answer my own question so I'm writing here. Why answers come to me just after i post :(

Comment: Oh, of course. Don't feel bad, I missed that too.

Answer (score 0):

qgraphicsitem_cast is defined in `#include <QGraphicsItem>`. Have you included this in the file in question?

Comment: I have answered myself in comment to the question. I knew it was so simple :(